# Why is Merrill Lynch taking money from Jordan Belfort and his team?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-wolf-of-wall-street

Surrounded by his team, Stratton Oakmont founder Jordan Belfort is
tossing a golf ball into glasses on a billiard table:

> Jordan Belfort: F-ck Merrill Lynch. F-ck them. Why should they be
> taking all our f-cking money all the f-cking time? This way we
> become the underwriters.

Why is Merrill Lynch taking money from Jordan Belfort and his team?

Comment: They're not actually *taking* money from Jordan, rather they are getting investors to invest with ML **instead** of Jordan... so they are getting the profit rather than him.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Underwriters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underwriting) charge a fee for their services. Merrill Lynch are not taking **all** of anyone's money, that's hyperbole, but they are charging for what they do. The character is saying that if they performed the actions themselves, they wouldn't need to pay the fee.

An equivalent thing for a person might be not using a real estate agent because you don't want to pay them a commission, but marketing and selling the house yourself. Such a person might say "why should the real estate agent get my money?"